# Error while creating JS file using java

Tags: java

I am writing a Java code through which I am creating a JavaScript file.
In script file, I want to write

```
var alertData = "Following characters are not allowed for value. [ $ & + , / : ; =? @ \" < > #    % { } | \\ ~ ^ [ ] ` ]";
```

When I compile code and call method to create a file,

```
Syntax Error: syntax error: > is not valid.
```

Can someone help?

More code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
sb.append("var validationAlertForValues = \"");
sb.append(("Following characters are not allowed for value. [ $ & + , / : ; =? @ \" < > # % { } | \\ ~ ^ [ ] ` ]"));
sb.append("\";\n    var validationAlertForKeys = \"");
sb.append(("Following characters are not allowed for key name.  [ $ & + , / : ; =? @ \" # % { } | ~ ^ [ ] ` &lt;space&lt; ] "));

 FileWriter fstream = null;
 BufferedWriter out = null;
 try {
   fstream = new FileWriter(filePath);
   out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
   out.write(sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in making JS", e);
        }
```

Comment: You need to post a lot more information, including the Java code that's writing the file and the output.

Comment: Syntax Error: syntax error: > is not valid. is JS Error when I use JS file

Comment: @chrylis- I am creating JS file during ant build and using that JS afterwords

Comment: You still haven't posted the Java code or the actual Javascript, and you're retyping the error message (incorrectly) instead of copying and pasting. We can't help you if you don't give us the specifics of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this Apache CommonLang StringEscapeUtils.

There are classes there to escape different type of input. Here is a sample i found.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strHTMLInput = "<P>MyName<P>";
        String strEscapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(strHTMLInput);
        String strUnEscapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(strEscapeHTML);
        System.out.println("Escaped HTML >>> " + strEscapeHTML);
        System.out.println("UnEscaped HTML >>> " + strUnEscapeHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `\"` which is escape character sign. Try use `\\"`.

Comment: @ProblemFactory- \\" is not giving any problem is JS